# how to to properly setup a linux server with kvm qemu for networking

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have two hosts (identical hardware) running two different linux-distributions. Both are running kvm-qemu, and I have copied the same qcow-file for a linux clients to both hosts. My network is using the address-space 192.168.2.x I want the client to show in this space. So I configured the interface as shared device with virbr0 of type virtio on both servers in virt-manager. For one server (name = virthost) the behavior is as expected: The client is visible as 192.168.2.6 throughout the network. With the second server (name=labpc1) the client gets the address 192.168.122.225. I can ping the client under this address from the server labpc1, but not from other hosts in the network. So obviously the server-config is somehow different.

```
[root@virthost buesser]# /sbin/ifconfig
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe4e:cb79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2c:4d:54:4e:cb:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 251712  bytes 20440529 (19.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1133838  bytes 1612893332 (1.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 270  bytes 15166 (14.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 270  bytes 15166 (14.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.50  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe4e:cb79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2003:c0:370e:3600:2e4d:54ff:fe4e:cb79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 2c:4d:54:4e:cb:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 234255  bytes 13306620 (12.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 717  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 230639  bytes 1504208543 (1.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe54:d2af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:54:d2:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 131040  bytes 113022492 (107.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 128330  bytes 149290254 (142.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe90:c278  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:90:c2:78  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 110307  bytes 145357136 (138.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 80834  bytes 60947380 (58.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe9a:7cd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:9a:07:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 117  bytes 9210 (8.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1250  bytes 128326 (125.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


[root@labpc1 ~]# /sbin/ifconfig
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::29e:8b0f:c0d4:ac95  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2003:c0:370e:3600:15ca:a8a2:5173:d03c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 34:97:f6:8e:c0:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7807  bytes 830450 (810.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 784  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5529  bytes 2526116 (2.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12376  bytes 2419241 (2.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12376  bytes 2419241 (2.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:38:47:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46  bytes 3516 (3.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 3052 (2.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe95:bcf3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:95:bc:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46  bytes 4160 (4.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 279  bytes 25326 (24.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So on labpc1 the physical interface gets the address of the host, and virbr0 gets 192.168.122.1 On virthost virbr0 has the (external) address of the physical host 192.168.2.50.

Can anybody shed some light?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It turn out:
only NAT is configured on CENTOS 8 by default.
After configuring for bridging it now works.

Wolfgang